# reactJS generating cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following reactJS state variables defined:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        passData: this.props.location.state,
        transferState: "0",
        numberOfFunds: 0,
        indicative: {
            functionUpdate: false,
            planName: '',
            familyID: '',
            planID: '',
            loc: '',
            memberID: '',
            PIN: '',
            mqMessage: ''  ,
            planMenuString: ''
            },
        data: {
            inv_FundAccurecordFundNumber: [],
            inv_FundMsgNumber: [],
            inv_FundName: [],
            inv_FundBalance: [],
            inv_FundAllocation: [],
            inv_FundPercent: [],
            inv_FundMinPct: [],
            inv_FundMaxPct: [],
            inv_FundTrsfInAllowed: [],
            inv_FundTrsfOutAllowed: []
            },
        currentTransfer: {
            intoFundNumber: [],
            intoFundName: [],
            intoPercent: []
            }
        }
        this.returnHome = this.returnHome.bind(this);
        this.buttonNext = this.buttonNext.bind(this);
        this.buttonCancel = this.buttonCancel.bind(this);
    }
```

And I have the following code:

```
renderIntoPercent = (index, fundNumber, fundName) => {
    console.log("index/fundNumber/fundName: ", index, fundNumber, fundName);
    let obj = {
        array: []
    };
    for (var l=0;l<=100;l++){
        obj.array[l] = l;
    }
    let optionItems = obj.array.map((item) =>
        <option key={item}>{item}</option>
    );
    return (
        <div className="col-2 text-left text_14">    
            <select value={this.state.currentTransfer.intoFundPercent[index]} 
                            onChange={(event) => this.handleIntoFundPercent(event, index, fundNumber, fundName)} >
                        {optionItems}
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I run the application, and the renderIntoPercent is executed the first time, I am passing in the values of 0, 04, and American Century Inflation-Adjusted Bond as the 3 parameters respectfully.

When the code executes, and I look at the console.log, I see the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>       at transferRebalance._this.renderIntoPercent (transferRebalance.js:412)

Here is an image of my code so you can see the line numbers:

[image]

And here is an image of the console.log():
[image]

I'm trying to renter a dropdown menu which will contain the values 1 - 100 and have the value populated by the state variable.  On change, I will execute the handleIntoFundPercent() where I will update the state variable.

My problem is the cannot read property '0' of undefined.  I'm not sure what property '0' is and I'm not sure what variable it thinks is undefined.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: please verify that this.state.currentTransfer.intoFundPercent is defined

Comment: You're trying to read `this.state.currentTransfer.intoFundPercent`. There is no `this.state.currentTransfer.intoFundPercent` in your state.

Comment: Sounds like `this.state.currentTransfer.intoFundPercent` is an empty array. And, on line 412 you're trying to access the `index`th (in the first iteration, 0th) element. Since it's empty, you get that error.

Comment: In your state you're defining `intoPercent` but not `intoFundPercent` in the `currentTransfer` object. Try `this.state.currentTransfer.intoPercent` and make sure that you is not an empty array.

Comment: Duh! Thank you all for pointing this out.  It's always something right in front of my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

`currentTransfer` object in the state is not include `intoFundPercent`

```
currentTransfer: {
            intoFundNumber: [],
            intoFundName: [],
            intoPercent: []
}
```

try to use `this.state.currentTransfer.intoPercent`